# Is [license-compatibility] the same as [compatibility]

Tags: discussion, tags

I was approving edits in the Suggested Edits queue while I came across this:

https://opensource.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/268

I approved it due to the description, we have a new tag. However, with a significant lack of tag wikis (For those of you who contribute, I applaud you), it's hard to tell the rationale for the tag creation, as well as what we should do with the tags.

So Meta! What's the difference and why should we use each one?

Comment: For everyone else's reference, I had no idea if the others should be removed, but I knew that [tag:license-compatibility] was in existence and would be good.

Comment: Yeah, I would prefer [tag:license-compatibility] over [tag:compatibility]. It's much more clear.

Comment: If a tag basically requires another tag it's generally better to hyphenate them. In this case I think it's better to have license-compatiblity than license and compatibility.

Comment: Oh no! I forgot the pun. Someone! Think of one quickly!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### We should only use [license-compatibility](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/license-compatibility)

Out of the currently 4 questions tagged with one or both of these tags, none of them is about anything other than license compatibility. Out of the two tags, [license-compatibility](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/license-compatibility) reflects this better/more clearly. There is likely no use-case for [compatibility](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compatibility), and if there were, it would be confusing to have these questions under the same tag as license compatibility questions.

I would suggest burninating [compatibility](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compatibility).

Comment: I agree with re-tagging questions. However, I think we should take [tag:compatibility] and see if there are other instances or categories to place it within, as we attempt to test the limits of the site's scope.

Comment: @Zizouz212 **if** the necessity arises, it can be recreated.

Comment: Some people may not think to type "license-compatibility", but this does not matter since anyone typing "compatibility" as a tag will see "license-compatibility" as a suggestion. So there is no need to have "compatibility" as a back up tag.