# Is the relicensing tag useful?

Tags: discussion, tags

I think it would be useful to have the tag [relicensing](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relicensing). Like we agreed for [license-compatibility](https://opensource.meta.stackexchange.com/q/139/190), I think it is better to have one tag like this than using two tags like [license](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/license) and [license-change](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/license-change) (which does exist and should probably eventually be made a synonym).

Here are some questions I think it should apply to:

- [Can I license a project which I have already released without a license?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/221/190)
- [How can a project be relicensed?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/33/190)
- [Can I license a project that I have built on if it already has a license?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/378/190)
- [If I include some GPL code in my project, can I release it as BSD?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/35/190)
- [Is it possible to close an open source project?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/270/190)
- [Can I place a license on something that I already published? [Duplicate]](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/408/190)

Now it is true that some of these concern things which were not previously released under a license. I think that the process of changing a license and the factors involved in choosing whether and how to do so are similar enough that they should use the same tag. But I'd be open to suggestions for a tag name which is equally applicable to such cases.

(This meta post was created because Zizouz212 retagged several of these questions.)

Answer (score 4):

I currently don't care if [relicensing](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relicensing) or [license-change](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/license-change) is better, but one of the two is useful for questions like the one mentioned in the OP. The other should be a synonym.

Comment: Exactly the same time... Not a second difference

Comment: It's a kind of magic :-)

Comment: Darn magic.....